# Erro de sintaxe Adjacent JSX React

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Criei um componente que há seis imagens porém ao compilar o meu código me retorna o seguinte erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E este é meu código fonte do componente ImovelPhotos

```
import React from 'react';

function ImovelPhotos (){
return (
    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem1-min.jpg")} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="responsive-photo" src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem2-min.jpg")} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem3-min.jpg")} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem4-min.jpg")} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem5-min.jpg")} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="responsive-photo" src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem6-min.jpg")} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem7-min.jpg")} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem8-min.jpg")} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default ImovelPhotos;
```

Comment: Não sei qual a versão do React que estás a usar mas normalmente precisas de ter somente 1 elemento pai. Ou seja, põe essas divs dento de uma única para retornares à função somente um elemento.

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de retornar somente 1 elemento no JSX. No Vue.js aplica-se também o mesmo principio.

No React 16 muda um pouco, mas tens na mesma de encapsular tudo com `<>` ou `<React.fragment>`, por isso uma `<div>` funciona igualmente bem.

Usa assim:

```js
import React from 'react';

function ImovelPhotos (){
  return (
      <div>
        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem1-min.jpg")} />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="responsive-photo" src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem2-min.jpg")} />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem3-min.jpg")} />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem4-min.jpg")} />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem5-min.jpg")} />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="responsive-photo" src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem6-min.jpg")} />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem7-min.jpg")} />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="responsive-photo " src={require("assets/img/imb/_imagem8-min.jpg")} />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default ImovelPhotos;
```